# Symfony createQueryBuilder JOIN

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get my products from repository
I have 3 tables:
- categories
- types which contains categorie_id
- produits which contains types_id

My twig view returns "variable produits does not exist"
What's going wrong in my querybuilder ?
Thanks

```
class ProduitsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {

    public function byCategorie($categorie) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p') // Entity Produits
                ->join('p.type', 't')
                ->addSelect('t') // Entity Types
                ->where('p.type = t.id AND t.categorie = :categorie')
                ->orderBy('p.id')
                ->setParameter('categorie', $categorie);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();      
    }
}
```

ok i add a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AahAT.png)

This is my controller

```
public function categorieAction($categorie)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $produits = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:Produits')->byCategorie($categorie);


    return $this->render('GbaBundle:Default:produits/layout/produits.html.twig', array(
        'produits' => $produits
    ));
}
```

---

This is my twig view produits.html.twig

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
             {% for produit in produits %}
            <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/holder.png') }}" alt="" width="300" height="300">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                        <p>100,00 €</p>

                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('gba_presentation') }}">Plus d'infos</a>

                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('gba_panier') }}">Ajouter au panier</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't post comments but you should give us your twig file, it might help us. Also, I don't think it will change anything but I would write the query like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p, t')
        ->join('p.type', 't')
        ->where('t.categorie = :categorie')
        ->orderBy('p.id')
        ->setParameter('categorie', $categorie);
```

Edit: Looking at your screenshot, it seems like you are rendering your view from the wrong controller action. You have one action called `categorieAction` and another one (which seems to be the wrong one) called `produitsAction`. You should make different routes for these two actions to avoid collisions.

Comment: Right  Thanks -- bad method called in my routing and I had erased the array in my render : array('produits' => $produits)); and  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $produits = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:Produits')->findAll();